# Why do programming languages (for example, Swift) not use the fastest available sort - bucket sort?

Tags: swift, performance, sorting, optimization, programming-languages

Benchmark of Swift's sort() which is timsort in compare to bucket sort:

**Number of items | Swift's sort() | Bucket sort | Difference:**

- 10,000 | 0.0403 seconds | 0.0058 seconds | x6.9
- 100,000 | 0.494 seconds | 0.059 seconds | x8.4
- 1,000,000 | 6.2 seconds | 0.68 seconds | x9.1
- 10,000,000 | 42 seconds | 8.2 seconds | x5.1
- 100,000,000 | 506 seconds | 94 seconds | x5.4

*Machine: iMac Pro (2017), 3.2 GHz Intel Xeon W. The values are for hardcoded `self.max()`. The provided code works little longer.*

Why do programming languages (including Swift) not use the faster bucket sort?

```
import Foundation

extension Array where Element == Int {
    mutating func sort() {
        guard count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        var count = [Element:Int]()
        for item in self {
            if count[item] != nil {
                count[item] = count[item]! + 1
            } else {
                count[item] = 1
            }
        }
        let n = self.max()!
        self = []
        for value in 0..<n {
            if let count = count[value] {
                for _ in 0..<count {
                    self.append(value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func sort(n: Int) {
    var array = [Int]()
    for _ in 0..<n {
        let newItem = Int.random(in: 0..<n)
        array.append(newItem)
    }
    let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    array.sort()
    let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    print("Time: \(end - start)")
}

sort(n: 1000000)
```

P.S. The memory consumption is almost the same.

## UPDATE

The following code works with any type but it's slower. But it's still little better than the current implementation of sort() method in Swift. So, the topic is actual only for sorting integers.

**Number of items | Swift's sort() | Bucket sort | Difference:**

- 10,000 | 0.0403 seconds | 0.0405 seconds | x1
- 100,000 | 0.494 seconds | 0.48 seconds | x1
- 1,000,000 | 6.2 seconds | 3.6 seconds | x1.7
- 10,000,000 | 42 seconds | 43 seconds | x1
- 100,000,000 | 506 seconds | not tested yet | ~x1

*Machine: iMac Pro (2017), 3.2 GHz Intel Xeon W*

```
import Foundation

extension Array where Element: Comparable & Hashable {
    mutating func sort() {
        var count = [Element:Int]()
        for item in self {
            if count[item] != nil {
                count[item] = count[item]! + 1
            } else {
                count[item] = 1
            }
        }
        self = []
        let keys = count.keys.sorted()
        for value in keys {
            if let count = count[value] {
                for _ in 0..<count {
                    self.append(value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func sort(n: Int) {
    var array = [Int]()
    for _ in 0..<n {
        let newItem = Int.random(in: 0..<n)
        array.append(newItem)
    }
    let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    array.sort()
    let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    print("Time: \(end - start)")
}

sort(n: 1000000)
```

Comment: Some remarks: Swift 5 uses timsort, not introsort. Your implementation is limited to arrays of integers, and does not work: `var a = [3, 4, 5] ; a.sort()` results in an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for the remark about timsort. But you're wrong. It works fine - please, check your corrections to the code. And it works with **any** type - not only Int - with few corrections.

Comment: Sorry, I posted a version for `Int` only by a mistake. I'll try to fix it back.

Comment: I posted the initial code that works with any type. Unfortunately, it works better only with 1,000,000 items - and it has the same performance in the remaining tests. So, the topic is still valid for sorting integers.

Comment: Your integer sort does not work, example given above. The general method requires the elements to be Hashable, not only Comparable. It  uses `count.keys.sorted()` which means that it *cannot* be faster than the built-in sort if all keys are distinct.

Comment: Output for [3, 4, 5] is [3, 4, 5]. The provided code works fine! Also it does't use `count.keys.sorted()` for integers!

Comment: Your first sort method (inside `extension Array where Element == Int`) does *not* work for `[3,4, 5]`. Make sure in your test that it is actually used, e.g. by renaming it to integer_bucket_sort.

Comment: It works for [3, 4, 5], believe me, I tested - specially for you. But the problem with my code is different. I found that it works so fast only because it supports integers up to 100,000,000...

Comment: Are we talking about the same code? This is what I tested: https://gist.github.com/martinr448/9367501c514e22e57c857c8a44668320.

Comment: Please replace the following lines: `self = []; let n = self.count // it's not always true, but it's true for the current implementation` with `let n = self.max()!; self = []`. Those lines were correct only in scope of the original code. I also fixed them in the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193205/discussion-between-martin-r-and-dmitry).

Comment: O(*n*) sorting algorithms are not suitable for all types, they may require prior knowledge about the input, and do allocate more memory.

Comment: And by the way your code is for [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), not [Bucket Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer is that:

1. Much better performance is observed only with integers;
2. The provided code works only with integers up to 100,000,000 - changing this will reduce the performance.

The universal code (see the "UPDATE" section) works with almost the same performance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "fastest sort" around, it depends on the data.

For example for data that is already sorted the fastest sort is bubble sort: you don't move anything and after just reading the input you know you're done. Even for data that is almost sorted there are cases in which (surprisingly enough) a variation on the bubble sort algorithm is a very reasonable choice (e.g. a linked list based scan line renderer where many x values are updated by small amounts from one scan line to the next).

Bucket sort is a very good choice in some cases but only if the key is small or if it can be partitioned in not too many small pieces (not always the case).

Quick sort and variations use random to avoid worst-case scenarios and only use less-than comparison between keys (something that's always available). It's a good default choice if not much is known about the data and it fits in fast random access memory.

Depending on the case may be you want to minimize the comparisons, or may be you want to minimize the swaps. It's not the same thing.

If data is too large for fast memory and random access on the whole set is problematic then merge sort is probably a good candidate.

...

In other words, it depends :-)

Your test case of sorting just an array of small integers is not very common in my experience.

Comment: Yes, it depends! So, the current implementation may work **slower**, but a bucket sort has a constant complexity across any data.

Comment: @Dmitry: how do you sort an array of names (variable length strings) with bucket sort? What does it mean `O(n)` where `n` cannot grow to infinity but is bounded by the physical limits of the computer?

Comment: I posted the code that works with strings. It's still faster for 1,000,000 strings when some of them are equal. But the initial topic is generally valid only for integers.

Comment: @Dmitry: a "bucket" sort for strings that uses a dictionary either: 1) is not O(n) but O(n log(n)) because uses a tree-based dictionary (e.g. red-black trees) or 2) is not sorting because uses an hash-based dictionary (how do you visit the buckets in order? by sorting unique keys? using which algorithm?).